# Не видна css переменная в MUI модалке <DIalog/> React

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, scss, mui

Начал писать приложение на реакт, столкнулся с проблемой, так как забыл mui модалку порталом ставит, из-за чего в модалке нету доступа к CSS переменной темы, так как при открытии модалки ее компонента вставляется парралельно компоненте приложения app.[image: введите сюда описание изображения] и навешиваются стили темы на app, как видно dark. Такой индекс файл [image: введите сюда описание изображения]. Такой тем провайдер [image: введите сюда описание изображения]. тем контекст[image: введите сюда описание изображения] ну и хук для получения и изменения темы[image: введите сюда описание изображения]. как это поправить, чтобы доступ был в модалке к стилям. В иделе надо было вешать на боди стили темы, но что-то торможу и не понимаю как это сделать с нынешней логикой

Comment: Код должен быть текстом, а не картинками

Comment: что от этого изменится?

Comment: Если кто то захочет скопировать код, что бы воспроизвести у себя и дать вам ответ, он это сделать не сможет. А желание перебивать код с картинки врят ли у кого то возникнет.

Comment: если бы был код. который вот так вот просто можно скопиравть и воспроизвести, я бы добавил код. А этот код увы не получится воспроизвести у себя, он добавлен больше для понимания того, как работает тема в приложении

Answer (score 0):

чтобы на бади навесить стили темы можно прописать такой хук

```
 useEffect(() => {
        document.body.className = theme
    })
```

предварительно получив тему из своего хука

Comment: Не решение, а какой то костыль. Тогда уже проще в css прописать стили для body